# Error when setting conditional RewriteRule to symlink folder with no permission

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permissions, symlink

I tried to redirect webroot.
Below is my situation:

```
htdocs# ls -la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 43 June 27 10:27 public -> /var/www/mydomain/htdocs/myproject/web
```

```
IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain$
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ https://mydomain/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^abc.html$[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ public/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The public/ is symlink folder which I want to show as the webroot. And for maintenance, permission for the original folder of the symlink, myproject/web, is now set 000. So permission error occurs when you access to index.php, for instance.
The problem is, error occurs even when you access to mydomain/acb.html and mydomain/.

Error shown is below:
`Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.`
(But I can visit the both page without error, using an IP address which is allowed to access to the SERVER; ie. listed in etc/hosts.allow .)

Any ideas to solve this?

---

I'm expecting abc.html and / are shown without problem when permission of the folder web is set 000.

By the way, I'm not confident if setting permission to 000 for symlink source is good way for maintenance. Or should I set 000 or 444 to the folder public?